# Kotlin: Idiomatic way to check for multiple boolean functions

Tags: android, kotlin

I am trying to validate a form by calling the same functions multiple times. My goal is that the `isFormValid` function should "wait" till all functions are called and then return the boolean.

My current solution works but it looks really od. Ain't there a better way?

### FormValidator Class

```
class FormValidator(private val context: Context) {

// some strings

private fun String.isValidEmail() = android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(this).matches()

fun validateNormalET(editText: MutableLiveData<String>, editTextEM: MutableLiveData<String>): Boolean {
    if (editText.value.isNullOrEmpty()) {
        editTextEM.value = emptyFieldError
        return false
    }
    return true
}

fun validateMinLengthET(editText: MutableLiveData<String>, editTextEM: MutableLiveData<String>, minLength: Int): Boolean {
    val errorMessage = when {
        minLength < 5 -> postCodeTooFewChar
        minLength < 7 -> btNumberTooFewChar
        else -> "Error"
    }
    if (editText.value.isNullOrEmpty()) {
        editTextEM.value = emptyFieldError
        return false
    } else if (editText.value.toString().length < minLength) {
        editTextEM.value = errorMessage
        return false
    }
    return true
}

fun validateEmail(editText: MutableLiveData<String>, editTextEM: MutableLiveData<String>): Boolean {
    if (editText.value.isNullOrEmpty()) {
        editTextEM.value = emptyFieldError
        return false
    } else if (!editText.value.toString().isValidEmail()) {
        editTextEM.value = emailNotValidError
        return false
    }
    return true
}
```

### Current isFormValid Function

```
fun isFormValid(): Boolean =
    formValidator.validateMinLengthET(btNumber, btNumberEM, 7) and
    formValidator.validateNormalET(etFirstName, etFirstNameEM) and
    formValidator.validateNormalET(etLastName, etLastNameEM) and
    formValidator.validateEmail(etEmail, etEmailEM) and
    formValidator.validateMinLengthET(etPostCode, etPostCodeEM, 5) and
    formValidator.validateNormalET(etCity, etCityEM) and
    formValidator.validateNormalET(etStreet, etStreetEM) and
    formValidator.validateNormalET(etHouseNumber, etHouseNumberEM)
```

I appreciate every help, thank you. If there was already a question like this, then I am sorry that I opened another one..

Comment: To make it a little shorter You can use ` with(formValidator) {}` scope so You won't have to write `formValidator` in every line. But still, it will be a long function

Comment: @iknow Looks like a step to the right direction but still really od. And would it check for all cases?

Comment: I am not sure but I think when You use `and` all functions will be executed but if You use `&&` operator functions after first `false` won't. So in Your case when `validateMinLengthET` returns `false` every other function isn't executed and `isFormValid` instantly returns `false`

Comment: @iknow yeah this works, but maybe there is better solution

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a list with its `.all` implementation:

```kotlin
fun isFormValid(): Boolean = listOf(
        formValidator.validateMinLengthET(btNumber, btNumberEM, 7),
        formValidator.validateNormalET(etFirstName, etFirstNameEM),
        formValidator.validateNormalET(etLastName, etLastNameEM),
        formValidator.validateEmail(etEmail, etEmailEM),
        formValidator.validateMinLengthET(etPostCode, etPostCodeEM, 5),
        formValidator.validateNormalET(etCity, etCityEM),
        formValidator.validateNormalET(etStreet, etStreetEM),
        formValidator.validateNormalET(etHouseNumber, etHouseNumberEM)
        )
        .all { it }
```

That way you're following the *Open/Closed Principle*.
If you want to make it slightly shorter, use `with(formValidator) {}`-scope like [@iknow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13363205/iknow) posted in the comment.

**EDIT**:
If you want it to use as little resources as possible, you could convert the list type to a boolean producer: `() -> Boolean`

```kotlin
fun isFormValid(): Boolean = listOf(
        { formValidator.validateMinLengthET(btNumber, btNumberEM, 7) },
        { formValidator.validateNormalET(etFirstName, etFirstNameEM) },
        ...
        )
        .all { it() }
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, how does this comply with open/closed principle? I see in either of the cases, you still have to modify the code if you're adding a new validation.

Comment: @SiddharthKamaria Open for extension: if you need another attribute, extend the list by your item; Closed for modification: The logic "all have to be true" will not change. On contrary to the `.. and .. and ..` solution, every `and` is a modification.

Comment: This looks like a good solution. But I have two questions: What exactly does "it" mean in .all and what is the benefit of using a boolean producer?

Comment: @Andrew I assume you're very new to kotlin, so I recommend you to [check this link](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#it-implicit-name-of-a-single-parameter) for the first question. The benefit of the producers, or lambdas here would be, that the functions inside are only executed when it is really necessary. If the first element is false already, the rest will never be executed and won't take a load from your cpu / threads / ... .

Comment: @Neo Okay, thank you, but I get a problem when using this approach. It says: Change lambda return type to () -> Boolean